# Unable to track bug when Live build uploaded to Play Store, working fine otherwise

Tags: android, android-studio, release

While building a signed apk from Android Studio, I am not getting any bug whatsoever. However, when the app is installed from the Play Store, I am not getting any data on the desired UI. I have integrated the following libraries **Crashlytics**, **Bugsnag** and **Sherlock** to trace the bug, but haven't found any crash report. Can anyone help me in finding out how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I am not getting any data on the desired UI."_ What kind of data should there be and how should it get there? Do you download it? Do you gather it with the device sensors? We currently know nothing about your app.

Comment: so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, after calling a particular API, I was supposed to get some data from the response, which I'm not getting.

Comment: How could anyone help you with just that information? We still have no idea of the actual problem. Maybe you call the API wrong and it doesn't have the data(?) Maybe it has the data, but you have trouble extracting it(?) Nobody knows. It's a complete mystery. :)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, I'm only speaking out what I am facing. If I'm calling the wrong API, how am I getting the data once I run it from code base using the signed APK? Yes, it's a complete mystery for me too.

Comment: Even an app installed from Play Store could write some logs to logcat unless of course you specifically disable that. Maybe logs could reveal something(?) What about error handling in the app in general? Could it show some useful error messages like "No connection to the xyz API" or "Parsing the xyz API data failed"? Anything that's not too confusing to an end user. Can you share any of the code that might be failing? Do you perhaps just catch exceptions in code without doing anything else? At least you can review the code yourself and think what could possibly fail and how.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, how can you track exceptions when you can't track an error message? It's not possible to share the code because if there was any problem with it, I would have got an error or exception once I generated the signed APK from the code base, and would not have to post the question here.

Comment: Not all programming errors cause exceptions. Sometimes the app just doesn't do what it's supposed to do. The coder can add logs at critical places to print out relevant information about the application flow. And then update the app to Play Store. And then stare at logcat while the app runs and doesn't do what is was expected to do.

Comment: It's not feasible to keep adding logs in your code, especially when it's your Live build, as it would consume more than the desired memory.